# Android - Display wrong position when I click on ListView item

Tags: android-listview, position

I am showing position in Toast when click on list item. But position get wrong. Why this type of problem generated. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                         Log.i("You clicked On ", arg2+"" );

    });
```

Comment: this the way i get my index with if it not works with you put sample from your code